# Unable to save excel to SharePoint 2007

Tags: 2007, excel

I have a user who is having issue saving changes he made to an excel file stored in a document library. He has contribute access to the library. The setting on the library does not require check out so when he clicks to open the file, it opens in read only mode. He clicks "Edit Workbook" and makes changes and clicks save button. All seems fine and no error message. But close the excel and reopen from the library and all changes are gone!

He is on IE 9 (32 bit) and Office Standard 2010 (32 bit). I read somewhere that disabling the "Microsoft Office Upload Centre" would fix the issue but that did not help either. I have also read another post with similar issue except there it was due to IE (64 bit) and seems to have solved once changed to 32 bit!

Much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

As it turned out, it was IE 64 bit issue! What happened was that the user had both version of IE installed on his pc. Every time he tried the excel, he used the 64 bit. but when I asked for the "About Internet Explorer", he always managed to send me the 32 bit version! Talk about wild goose chase...

Answer (score 0):

You should see if http://support.microsoft.com/kb/870853 applies to your situation. I had similar issues, with attachments to list items, and the fix it for me worked just fine. Your changes are not being saved because the document is Read Only.